# Emacs - Load ParEdit Mode on Startup

Tags: emacs, paredit

Is there a straightforward way to enable paredit mode by default every time I launch emacs? I have this code in my .emacs:

```
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(show-paren-mode 1)
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode 1)
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(global-linum-mode t)
(paredit-mode 1)
```

Every mode except for paredit-mode gets loaded. Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to enable Paredit globally:

> Paredit behaves badly if parentheses are unbalanced, so exercise caution when forcing Paredit Mode to be enabled, and consider fixing unbalanced parentheses instead.

Instead, you can invoke it for modes where it makes sense, e.g.

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of those modes, only `paredit-mode` is buffer-local (i.e. is activated independently for each buffer), all others are global.  So if you enable `paredit-mode` like you do in your `~/.emacs`, it will activate it in the buffer that happens to be current when that code is loaded (usually it's the `*scratch*` buffer), but not in subsequent file buffers you'll visit.

You want to use something like

```
(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
```

if you want to enable it in buffers that use `foo-mode`.